# como faço para mandar um parametro qualquer via href e receber no controller resource em Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Fiz uma tela que terá um botão para visualizar e outro para editar, porém no href no botão tenho `{{route('products.index', 'E')}}` minha rota esta assim:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

meu controller está assim:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $url_segment = \Request::segment(2);
        dd($url_segment);

        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('products.index', compact('products'))
                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1)* 5);
    }
```

na view que retorna no método acima terá que verificar o parâmetro mandado pelo o href da primeira view.

exemplo:

```
@if($parametro == 'E')
    mostrar o botão de editar
@else
    não mostra
@endif
```

como vocês podem ver eu tentei o segment porém não está dando certo como que faria isso no controller?

obs: no retorno no `dd($url_segment);` me trás null.

O que quero fazer é só recuperar o parâmetro do href no controller resource no método index

porém quando tento receber

```
public funcion index($id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

me retorna o erro abaixo:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::index(), 0 passed and exactly
>   1 expected.

Comment: Por que você não criar uma exceção com, `except` no seu arquivo de rota e assim poder recriar a rota *.index* passando argumento? É apenas uma sugestão.